# Confusion about definition of orthogonal projection

Tags: operator-theory

My professor gave the definition of orthogonal projection as follows : Let H be inner product space. If P $\in \mathbb B(H)$(continuous operator) such that $P^{2}=P$ and ker(P)= (range$P)^\perp$, then it is orthogonal projection. My question is does it is necessary that to include condition P $\in \mathbb B(H)$ as every projection may not be continuous.

Comment: ??? If every projection need not be continuous that says it _is_ necessary to include that condition in the definition.

Comment: my question was what would happen if we just put condition that $P^2=P$ and ker(P)= (range$P)^\perp$?

Comment: I understood that was your question! You might consider reading the answer I posted, if you can spare the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $P\in\Bbb B(H)$ is indeed redundant. But not because every projection need to be continuous; it's redundant because any $P$ satisfying the rest of the definition *must* be continuous.

Indeed, suppose $P:H\to H$ is linear, $P^{2}=P$ and $ker(P)= (range P)^\perp$. For every $x\in H$ we have $$P(x-Px)=0,$$so $$x=y+Px,\quad Py=0.$$Since the range and kernel of $P$ are othogonal this shows that $$||x||^2=||y||^2+||Px||^2\ge||Px||^2,$$so $||P||\le1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I was having some other confusions also but that too got solved by above answer!!!